# Does XGBoost distinguish between missing values and 0s in a sparse matrix in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

Sometimes features can have 0s *and* missing values.  For example, maybe you measure the strike-outs per game per pitcher for a set of baseball pitchers, and you end up with a feature vector like

```
feats <- c(NA, NA, NA, 3.7, 0, 2.2)
```

Here, 1 pitcher averaged 0 strikeouts per game and 3 pitchers didn't log any data because they haven't pitched a game yet.  When we convert this to a sparse matrix we get something like

```
library(Matrix)
sparse1 <- sparseMatrix(i=4:6, j=rep(1, 3), x=c(3.7, 0, 2.2), dims=c(6, 1))
sparse1

[1,] .  
[2,] .  
[3,] .  
[4,] 3.7
[5,] 0.0
[6,] 2.2
```

Here, the `dgCMatrix` class clearly distinguishes missing data from 0s, but from what I understand, missing data in a `dgCMatrix` is assumed to take on the value 0.

What I'm wondering is, when XGBoost attempts to split this data, does it treat the 0s and the missing data separately?  In other words, when XGBoost tries to split on this feature, does it follow the NA protocol (checking both split directions) for the missing data, or does it send the missing data to the same location as the non-sparse 0 values?

Comment: Seems like with a small example you could empirically test this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the exact question though:

yes, a missing value is not considered for the gain computation (does not add to the sum of gradient and hessian of the children in a boosting tree) while a 0 value is considered (and adds to the sum of gradient and hessian of the children in a boosting tree)

So, a 0 and a missing value is not the same.

Comment: I was mostly confused because I thought the `dgCMatrix` matrix was storing missing values as NAs but it actually stores them as 0s.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you explicitly specify the representation of the sparse matrix.  All others are implicitly assumed to be zeros.  They are shown to be dots but this does not mean they are NAs.  `as.matrix()` will show that those dots are actually zeros.

```
library(Matrix)
sparse1 <- sparseMatrix(i=4:6, j=rep(1, 3), x=c(3.7, 0, 2.2), dims=c(6, 1))
as.matrix(sparse1)
```